# Adhering to Google's Structured Data Policy

Tags: googlebot, google-rich-snippets, rating-system, structured-data

Google's [`Product` structured data reference](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product) recommends that `aggregateRating` be included. [Common structured data errors](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/prototype#common-sd-errors) document says:

> The content referred to by the structured data is hidden from the user.

My question is how to verify that Google understands my UI? I'm using (5) svg star images to indicate the rating but there's 3 flavors of star, empty, half and full. Do I need to add a `content="rating"` or `title="rating"` attribute or …? I'd like to understand how does Google know I'm showing the 5 stars at all? I could be using `.png` files, or unicode ★.

```json
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "88",
    "bestRating": "100",
    "ratingCount": "20"
  }
```

Comment: Try [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console). If you go to the old version, you have a tool on [Structured Data](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/structured-data?hl=en) which can help you validate. Documentation can also be found on [this article](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google doesn’t document how they verify if the visible content matches the structured data. As long as you don’t hide/omit the content, it should be fine.

For this and all the other reasons, it would make sense to use accessible, semantic markup. If it’s accessible to users with disabilities, it’s typically also accessible to search engine bots.

In the case of ratings, you [could use](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/114796/17633) the [`meter` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/sec-forms.html#the-meter-element):

```html
<meter min="0" max="5" value="3">★★★☆☆</meter>
```

(As `meter` is probably not widely supported, you might want to consider using WAI-ARIA in addition: [example with `img` elements and `aria-labelledby`](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_aria-labelledby_to_provide_a_text_alternative_for_non-text_content#Example_2).)

Comment: Good info. Thanks. In those cases where `<meter>` is not supported  ([IE and iPhone/Safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meter)), I suppose the element's are simply disregarded but the `<meter>` children (the star images) remain in the HTML. So, I guess it can't hurt to use `<meter>`. Re: aria-labelledby to provide a text alternative, can the text alternative element be hidden? ...in other words, why would I display (4 of 5) next to the star images?

Comment: Turns out that `<meter>` is default styled by the browser and overwrites/hides my pretty svg stars so `<meter>` does not work. ....also, there's not a `role` available to markup a `<div>` as a meter or rating...? https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#XHTMLRoleVocabulary

Comment: @RonRoyston: With support, I was mainly thinking about accessibility tools (e.g., screen readers that don’t recognize the `meter`-specific attributes). -- Regarding `role`, yes, I guess there is none. -- For the WAI-ARIA label, it should be fine to visually hide it (so have it as part of HTML, but hide it via CSS so that it still gets read by screen readers); however, such a label is for accessibility, not SEO (I’d guess search engines simply ignore it).

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I found a `role` called `figure` which seems to be as close as I can get. So, I did a `div role="figure" describedBy="myFigure"` with `<span id="myFigure" class="hidden">5 of 5</span>` embedded as the first sibling of the star `svg`'s.